# How can I ensure correct grouping in a Django subquery annotation?

Tags: django, django-models, subquery, django-subquery

When I'm writing Django Subquery expressions, sometimes I have no idea how Django is going to group the result.

Example:

```py
subquery = (
    RelatedModel.objects.filter(
        category="some_category",
        grandparentmodel=OuterRef("relatedmodel__grandparentmodel"),
        mymodel__created_at__date=OuterRef("created_at__date"),
    )
    .values("grandparentmodel", "mymodel__created_at__date")
    .annotate(net=Sum("mymodel__amount"))
    .values("net")[:1]
)


query = (
    MyModel.objects.annotate(
        net=Coalesce(
            Subquery(subquery), Decimal("0.00")
        )
    )
)
```

With this, my goal is to group a bunch of `ParentModel` instances (with category `"some_category"`) by `grandparentmodel` and `mymodel__created_at__date`.

This seems to work only if I include the `.values("mymodel__created_at__date")` before my annotation. If I do not include that before my annotation of `net`, the subquery still runs and just gives incorrect `net`. However, the `.values("grandparentmodel")` seems not required to get the correct grouping; I can exclude it and I still get the values I'm expecting.

What's going on behind the scenes? How would I know to use a `.values()` call before my annotation to group correctly? How would I know what to include in said `values()` call? Is there some rule of thumb to follow when aggregating in subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the ORM isn't here to construct exact SQL queries. It is more a tool to transcript your needs into the best query it can find.
However, what you found is the way to force grouping.

```py
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs = qs.values("foo", "bar")  #  Fields used for grouping
qs = qs.annotate(res=Func("baz"))  # Aggregation on other fields
```

On itself `.values()` will discard the Model layer and change the queryset results the be dicts containing the keys given as parameters.
Followed by `.annotate()` containing an aggregation function on a field that is not in the `.values()` parameters, it will result in a group by. Results will also be dicts